# Bootstrap typeahead and bloodhound image

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ternary-operator, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I have the following code where i am showing a returned result from the search,

**Everything looks fine, But if the a database column is empty i am showing a default image, And the if the column have image address then the image is showing but the default image is not working.**

Note : I have used the ternary operator if the a column is null then show the default image, If not then show the returned column data which is the image address.

```
suggestion: function (data) {
    return '<a href="' + data.uuid + '" class="list-group-item">'+ data.image_front == null ? '<img src="' + assetBaseUrl + 'images/pet-fimage.jpg">' : '<img src="' + data.image_front +'">' + data.name + '- @' + data.mpc_number + '</a>'
}
```

Comment: What does the rendered text look like? I suspect it's malformed.

Comment: a guess: wrap the ternary operation in parenthesis.